# Trying to send different emails in a specific order with nodemailer and cron

Tags: javascript, cron, nodemailer

As I said, the plan is to have a web where you click and you receive an email, after some time a    different email and be like that until you reach the last one. Then, no more messages are sent.

I've tried to do a email array and pass it in a for loop. What happens is that the for loop activates and reach every email, but cron doesn't send it in time, it doesn't matter the time I write.

```
const express= require('express');
const app= express();
const nodemailer= require('nodemailer');
require('dotenv').config();
const cron= require('node-cron');

const PORT= process.env.PORT || 2525;


//Middleware
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/contactform.html')
```

})

```
app.post('/', (req, res)=>{
console.log(req.body);

const transporter= nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: "creativoasueldo@gmail.com",
        pass: "hhixfdgyrlcablfy",
    }
})

   

const mailOptions= [
   {
from: "creativoasueldo@gmail.com",
to: req.body.email,
subject: 'Mensaje 1', 
text: "Hello", 
cronExpression: "*/6 * * * *"
},
{
    from: "creativoasueldo@gmail.com",
    to: req.body.email,
    subject: 'Mensaje 2', 
    text: "Hola",
    cronExpression: "5 */7 * * * *"
    }, 
    {
        from: "creativoasueldo@gmail.com",
        to: req.body.email,
        subject: 'Mensaje 3', 
        text: "Allo",
        cronExpression: "10 */8 * * * *"
        }, 
       {
            from: "creativoasueldo@gmail.com",
            to: req.body.email,
            subject: 'Mensaje 4', 
            text: "Buona Sera",
            cronExpression: "15 */9 * * * *"
            }, 
            {
                from: "creativoasueldo@gmail.com",
                to: req.body.email,
                subject: 'Mensaje 5', 
                text: "Konichiwa",
                cronExpression: "20 */10 * * * *"
                }]

                
             
                for (let i = 0; i < mailOptions.length;  i++) {
                    const {cronExpression, from, to, subject, text} =mailOptions[i];    
                    console.log('Hola', to, i, mailOptions.length);                   
                     cron.schedule(cronExpression, ()=> { transporter.sendMail(mailOptions[i], (error, info)=>{
                            if(error){
                                console.log(error);
                                res.send('error');
                            }else {
                                console.log('Email sent'); 
                            }

                       
                    });
                } );
                console.log('Hola');
                //cron.stop(5 * 60 * 1000);
                

                    
                } 


})


app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
console.log(`Server running on ${PORT}`);
 })
```

Comment: Each mail has its own cronExpression, so that is an implicit order.